# What does the "crt" abbreviation mean in certificates?

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl, certificate-authority

I can find what all the other abbreviations mean like PEM and CSR as is mentioned here:

> https://pki-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

but what does CRT stand for?

Comment: When it comes to file naming and extensions for keys/certs, things are very inconsistent. I wouldn't bet on anything, and just examine contents to see if it is a key/cert, a bundle of certs, maybe PEM, or DER encoded, maybe a pkcs12 file. But it is most commonly a PEM encoded certificate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just an abbreviation of "certificate" (though `.cer` is used as well).

[Another page](https://pki-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mime.html) on the site you found lists them:

```
application/x-x509-ca-cert          .crt .der
application/x-x509-user-cert        .crt
```